# Jquery disable and enable input box for IE 6 and above

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jscript

first of all thanks to [DelightedD0D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376624/delightedd0d),

ok, now i having a problem with enable and disabled input box for IE 6.0 and above. below code can be run in other browser and i really need to do so in IE, is there any idea to do so?. because I have try to edit it, using *.attr*, change the input type attributes from *disabled* to *readonly* and also not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name="txt1"]').blur(function() {
    var $this=$(this);
    var $that = $('[name="txt2"]');
    if (this.value != '') {
      $this.prop('disabled',true);
      $that.prop('disabled',false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
input 1
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" />
<br>input 2
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2" disabled/>
```

---

> thanks to all, but i am finally manage to solve it, i just change the
>   ***script src:*** to the version of 1.x, so now its working.

Comment: jQuery 2.1.0 doesn't support IE6, fortunately... Are you really in need to support IE6?!

Comment: yes i am, since i was building a web-base application for window CE 7 device that use IE6 or 7..any idea then?

Comment: Firstly, you should use a jq 1.x branch version if not already the case.  https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: well thats the problem, because I'm not very familiar with jquery..thanks by the way..